# Bigquery avoid null data and merge rows

Tags: google-bigquery

In Google Bigquery, i'm having data sets with data dispersed between int_value and double value, how can i merge the

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|user_id | params.string_value | params.int_value | params.double_value |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 12     | null                |  null            | 121                 |
| 12     | Tom                 |  null            | null                |
| 12     | null                |  null            | 141                 |
| 12     | Kim                 |  null            | null                |
| 13     | null                |  null            | 961                 |
| 13     | Jack                |  null            | null                |
| 14     | null                |  null            | 31                  |
| 14     | Jerry               |  null            | null                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Result needed

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|user_id | params.string_value | params.int_value | params.double_value |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 12     | Tom                 |  null            | 121                 |
| 12     | Kim                 |  null            | 141                 |
| 13     | Jack                |  null            | 961                 |
| 14     | Jerry               |  null            | 31                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There can be multiple data for same user_id but with different params.string_value | params.int_value | params.double_value

I want to merge all the data which has same user_id in Big Query

Comment: Why does the "121" figure about Tom's line go from the double_value to int_value in the expected result?

Comment: Sorry my bad, i'm editing the answer

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT user_id, STRUCT(string_value, int_value, double_value) params
FROM (
  SELECT user_id,
    ARRAY_AGG(params.string_value IGNORE NULLS) string_values,
    ARRAY_AGG(params.int_value IGNORE NULLS) int_values,
    ARRAY_AGG(params.double_value IGNORE NULLS) double_values
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY user_id
)
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(string_values) string_value WITH OFFSET
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(int_values) int_value WITH OFFSET USING(OFFSET)
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(double_values) double_value WITH OFFSET USING(OFFSET)
```

If to apply to sample data from  your question

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 12 user_id, STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, double_value FLOAT64>(NULL, NULL, 121) AS params UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, STRUCT('Tom', NULL, NULL) UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, STRUCT(NULL, NULL, 141) UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, STRUCT('Kim', NULL, NULL) UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, STRUCT(NULL, NULL, 961) UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, STRUCT('Jack', NULL, NULL) UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, STRUCT(NULL, NULL, 31) UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, STRUCT('Jerry', NULL, NULL) 
)
```

result is

```
Row user_id params.string_value params.int_value    params.double_value  
1   12      Tom                 null                121.0    
2   12      Kim                 null                141.0    
3   13      Jack                null                961.0    
4   14      Jerry               null                31.0
```

Comment: Nice use of `OFFSET` ! Learned something today, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`MAX`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#max) function :

```sql
SELECT user_id,
       MAX(params.string_value) as string_value,
       MAX(params.int_value) as int_value,
       MAX(params.double_value) as double_value
FROM your_dataset.your_table
GROUP BY user_id
```

`MAX` do not consider `NULL` values. Neither do `MIN` so you can also use this one !

Comment: as you know Google BigQuery will be having multiple rows of data for same user_id so max will take the maximum data it won't merge.

Comment: i have updated the dataset in the question can you please check

Comment: Ok so now i don't understand what you call 'merging'. Do you want to have all possible combinaisons of string/int/double for each uuid ? A good way for me to understand would be to provide the expected result table in your question :)

Comment: Updated the question with Result data

Comment: What you call merging is clearer now. Unfortnulately it looks hard to get what you want. There is no rule on how to combine string and int/double value. In you example, how to know wether Tom has to be combined with 121 or 141 ?

Comment: its combined with the upper row because the user_id of the Tom row is matched

Comment: the user_id of the Tom Row is also matched with the lower row. If you don't have a logical condition other than "upper", it's hard to tell BigQuery how to match values.